# Django vs webapp2 on App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

I would like to know your opinion of which of these two web frameworks (Django & webapp2) is better for using on App Engine Platform, and why?

Please don't say that both are completely different, because Django is much more complete. Both are the "web frameworks" you can use in App Engine.

Comment: Since the release of Google Cloud SQL, you can already use Django in App Engine with it's full power. If you're already familiar with Django, then there's no reason to use webapp2 anymore, unless it's just a small project where using Django might just seem to be an overkill.

Comment: If you can use google's mysql, is django best choice.
But if you can use some datastore for storing data, webapp2 is better, becose, is very light framework, specialy for AppEngine. Django have some functionality (working with files, ... ) with is not available on AppEngine. 
You can use more another python framework on AppEngine, for example: [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#deploying-to-a-web-server)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: django and webapp2 are 2 completely different things and you really can't compare them. i wouldn't use django on appengine because it is not made for it. its like you want to compare a sailing boat to an oil tanker.

Comment: I'm no python expert, but IMHO a more fair comparison would be between a microframework like Flask (http://flask.pocoo.org/) and webapp2

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Choosing between Django and webapp2 really depends on what you're using it for.  In your question you haven't given any of the parameters for your decision making, so it's impossible to tell which is "better".  Describing them both as "web frameworks" shows you haven't done much research into what they are.

Webapp2 is essentially a request handler.  It directs HTTP requests to handlers that you write.  It's also very small.

Django has a request handler.  It also has a template engine.  It also has a forms processor.  It also has an ORM, which you may choose to use, or not.  Note that you can use the ORM on CloudSQL, but you'll need to use Django-nonrel if you want to use the ORM on the HRD.  It also has a library of plugins that you can use, but they'll only work if you're using the Django ORM.  It also has bunch of 3rd party libraries, which will also require the Django ORM.

If you have portability in mind the Django ORM would help a lot.

You'll have to make your decision comparing what you actually need.

Comment: can I use webapp2 code in django framework?